# Unexpected errors when building for profile in XCode 4.5

Tags: xcode, ios5, profile, xcode4.5

I have a project that I refactored for iOS 5 and ARC. It builds and runs fine, Analyzer finds nothing and I'm on the brink of submitting it to the App store. Before doing that, I thought it would be a good idea to check for leaks, just in case I missed something during the arcification. However when I choose "Product -> Profile" from the XCode 4.5 menu I get a flood of warnings and errors. All of them indicate that the build for profiling is not recognizing that the project is using ARC. The scheme settings for profile are set to use the same arguments and environment variables as run, but run works and profile doesn't. If I choose the "Profile without building" action, everything works. I've checked to make sure that there is only one version of XCode installed, checked the path, and it's all good. This is not a show stopper, but I'd like to know what's happening, and what setting to tweak if that's all it is.

Comment: If you have a helpful answer you should accept it. Click on checkmark under upvote/downvote counter. This will mark the question as "answered" and provide you with small reputation bonus. See [How do I ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) FAQ article.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by deleting project.xcworkspace and xcuserdata folder from the project bundle. Apparently they got corrupted somewhere along the line.